# How to give array of spans bottom border at specific index? ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, react-redux

so what this does it checks the words that are inputted by user and compares to text array, how can i give bottom Border to a span which should be inputted next?

```
return <span>{val}</span>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your `style` object (change the border style as you like):

```js
borderBottom: index === this.state.userInput.length && '3px solid #f00'
```

Explanation: If `index === this.state.userInput.length` evaluates to `true`, the whole expression evaluates to the string. If it evaluates to `false`, the whole expression evaluates to `false` (so no border is rendered).